# VB6 pass an object variable back to opening form

Tags: forms, vb6

How do I do this? I thought that I could pass the form as a variable to the child form. Then the child form could set a variable (as public property) on the parent form.

But I get some weird "function or interface marked as restricted" error.

Whats the way to do this in vb6??

Is it just a case of making the object a global variable?

thanks.

Comment: Posting relevant portions of code may help

Comment: Code sample please.  You can pass form reference around just fine, with some minor exceptions.

Comment: it should work. Code please, and exact error message and line where error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often when you create a Form in a Project, you make use of the global predeclared instance anyway.  So in such cases you have no need to pass anything as a parameter and no extra global reference to declare and set.

Just use the one you get "for free."  From your Form2 you can make use of Form1 with no extra coding.

That goes out the window (!) if you are doing anything more complex though, like wanting to touch more than one different Form in some procedure.  There you'd pass the Form as an argument.